# How to insert the record that has a foreign key using lifted embedded syntax on slick

Tags: scala, insert, foreign-keys, slick

I'd like to insert a new record that contains a foreign key.
For example, inserting the new record to bars, and the new record has the id that is found by the query result of the table foos.

Here is a code example:

```
import scala.slick.driver.H2Driver.simple._

object Test {
  case class FooRecord(id:Int, str: String)
  class Foos(tag: Tag)  extends Table[FooRecord](tag, "users") {
    def id  = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey)
    def str = column[String]("EMAIL", O.NotNull)
    def * = (id, str) <> (FooRecord.tupled, FooRecord.unapply _)
  }
  val foos = TableQuery[Foos]

  case class BarRecord(app_id:Int, name: String)
  class Bars(tag: Tag)  extends Table[BarRecord](tag, "apps") {
    def foo_id = column[Int]("FOO_ID")
    def str    = column[String]("STR", O.NotNull)
    def * = (foo_id, str) <> (BarRecord.tupled, BarRecord.unapply _)
    def foo_fk = foreignKey("FOO_FK", foo_id, foos)(_.id)
  }
  val bars = TableQuery[Bars]

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    Database.forURL("jdbc:h2:mem:test1", driver = "org.h2.Driver") withSession {
      implicit session =>
        foos.filter(_.str === "ABC").map { f =>
          // Insert a new record that contains foo's id as a foreign key to bars.

          // bars.insert(BarRecord(f.id, "DEF"))

          // [error]  found   : scala.slick.lifted.Column[Int]
          // [error]  required: Int

          bars.insert(BarRecord(1, "DEF"))       // OK
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I got a compile error. The type of the foreign key is Column[Int], but the BarRecord id type is Int. 
Is there any good way to get Int value? Or is there a more elegant way that can insert the value that is from another table's query result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query returns the lifted query, not the `Int` value:

```
val fooIdColumn: lifted.Query[lifted.Column[Int], Int] = 
  foos.filter(_.str === "ABC").map(f => f.id)
```

You can use `run` and get back a `Seq[Int]` (since there could be more than one result):

```
val fooIds: Seq[Int] = 
  foos.filter(_.str === "ABC").map(x => x.id).run
```

Or `firstOption` and `getOrElse` to get back an `Int`:

```
val fooId: Int = 
  foos.filter(_.str === "ABC").map(x => x.id).firstOption.getOrElse(0)
```